# undefined index

Tags: php

I transferred a file from my server that works well on the internet to my local computer.

And it throws a lot of undefined index for my variables,

please tell me what could be the problem as it works well on the internet and not working locally

below is the error and related code

> "Notice: Undefined index: Add in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 27 Notice:
>   Undefined index: Sname in /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php
>   on line 30 Notice: Undefined index: Pname in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 31 Notice:
>   Undefined index: Pidno in /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php
>   on line 32 Notice: Undefined index: Psize in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 33 Notice:
>   Undefined index: Pcolour in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 34 Notice:
>   Undefined index: Pquantity in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 35 Notice:
>   Undefined index: Weblink in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 36 Notice:
>   Undefined index: Price in /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php
>   on line 37 Notice: Undefined index: comment in
>   /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php on line 38 Warning:
>   date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You
>   are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for
>   'BST/1.0/DST' instead in /Users/mgltd/Sites/reacheasy/youraccount.php
>   on line 39"

the code

```
<?php
    $submit = $_POST['Add'];
    //form data
    $Sname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Sname'])));
    $Pname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pname'])));
    $Pidno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pidno'])));
    $Psize = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Psize'])));
    $Pcolour = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Pcolour'])));
    $Pquantity = $_POST['Pquantity'];
    $Weblink = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Weblink'])));
    $Price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['Price'])));
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['comment'])));
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    //echo " ('','$Sname','$Pname','$Pidno','$Psize','$Pcolour','$Pquantity','$Weblink','$Price','$Uname')";
    if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
    if ($Sname&&$Pname&&$Pidno&&$Weblink&&$Price)
    {
    if (is_numeric($Price))
    {
        $repeatheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac WHERE Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}' AND Pidno ='$Pidno' AND Sname='$Sname' AND Pname='$Pname'");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($repeatheck);
    if($count!=0)
    {
        die ('PRODUCT ALREADY IN BASKET YOU CAN INCREASE OR DECREASE QUANTITY, <a href="youraccount.php">CLICK TO GO BACK TO YOUR LIST</a>');
    }
    else
    //echo'$Price';
    $tprice = $Price * $Pquantity;
    //echo"$tprice";
    $queryreg = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO repplac VALUES ('','$Sname','$Pname','$Pidno','$Psize','$Pcolour','$Pquantity','$Weblink','$Price','$comment','$tprice','$date','{$_SESSION['username']}','')
    ")or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    echo 'price field requires numbers';
    }
    else
    echo 'please fill in all required * fields ';
    }
    ?>
    <form action='youraccount.php' method='Post' class='ilistbar'>
        <!--<div>
        <label for='shoppinglist' class='fixedwidth'></label>
        <textarea type='text' name='shoppinglist' id='username' cols='100' rows='15'></textarea>
        </div> -->
        <div>
        <label for='Sname' class='fixedwidth'> * Shop name</label>
        <input type='text' name='Sname' id='Sname'/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Pname' class='fixedwidth'> * Product name</label>
        <input type='text' name='Pname' id='Pname'/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Pidno' class='fixedwidth'> * Product id no /ad reference</label>
        <input type='text' name='Pidno' id='Pidno'/>
        (This should be unique for each product)
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Psize' class='fixedwidth'>Product size</label>
        <input type='text' name='Psize' id='Psize'/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Pcolour' class='fixedwidth'>Product colour</label>
        <input type='text' name='Pcolour' id='Pcolour'/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Pquantity' class='fixedwidth'>Product quantity</label>
        <select name="Pquantity" id="Pquantity">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
         <option value="5">5</option>
         <option value="6">6</option>
         <option value="7">7</option>
         <option value="8">8</option>
         <option value="9">9</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    (You can update quantity in excess of 10 on the shopping list below)
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Weblink' class='fixedwidth'> * Web link</label>
        <input type='text' name='Weblink' id='Weblink'/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='Price' class='fixedwidth'> * Price GBP</label>
        <input type='text' name='Price' id='Price'/>
        Please valid format is (.) for decimal
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for='comment' class='fixedwidth'> Extra info</label>
        <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment'/>
        Please give different colours , sizes of the same products,discount codes, and other information that you would like us to use
        </div>
        <div>

        <div class='buttonarea'>
                <p>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add'>
                </p>
                </div>
                </p>
        </form>
```

Comment: It fails on the server too. You just never hear about it there.

Comment: It's because you don't have the sever PHP set to display warnings. The code works just the same, you just haven't seen the warnings before.

Comment: That's some quality code and error messages right there, I tell you what.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap the php-block at the top in an if:

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){ 

    // Rest of the code that populates the variables and so on

}
```

This would ensure that you don't try to operate on values that aren't even remotely there. :)

Comment: @ninetwozero, it helped to remove the undefined error, but why is it not displaying that on the server, any ideas

Comment: Because your buttons name is ``submit``, not ``Add``. Check the code change above. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like the `$_POST` superglobal isn't populated (have you checked this?) or, at least, it doesn't contain what you think it does.

Your code seems to be assuming the POST values without checking.

Run `print_r($_POST)` - does it contain the right data?